# Решение задачи с помощью цикла for

Tags: c, алгоритм

Есть такая задача:

> Начав тренировки, спортсмен в первый день пробежал 10 км. Каждый день он увеличивал норму на 10% нормы предыдущего дня. Какой суммарный путь пробежит спортсмен за 7 дней?

Нужно решить с помощью цикла `for`. Я так понимаю, цикл будет примерно такой:

```
s=10
k=10
for(k=s*0,1+k)
    s+=s*0,1
```

И как мне здесь вывести результат? Нужно задать переменную, или как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, как бы, да, идея верная, только записать нужно было все правильно.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float today, total;
    unsigned int day;

    /* Ситуация на первый день. Пробежали 10 км, как за день, так и всего. */
    total = today = 10.0;
    /* Цикл со 2 по 7 дни, включительно. */
    for (day = 2; day <= 7; day++) {
        /* Каждый очередной день пробегаем 110% от предыдущего дня.
           Можно было написать хоть today = today + today * 0.1, но это некрасиво. */
        today *= 1.1;
        /* Добавляем пробег очередного дня */
        total += today;
        /* Выводим промежуточный результат.
           Вообще, он не нужен — это только, чтобы запустить и посмотреть как
           в цикле все происходило. Потом убрать. */
        printf("day %d: %0.2f km, total: %0.2f km\n", day, today, total);
    }
    /* Собственно, выводим суммарный пробег. */
    printf("%0.2f km\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем выводить промежуточные результаты? вынесите "принт" за цикл.

Comment: хм :) добрый человек не могли вы бы написать коментарии к программе, а то я не все понял :) в особенности что значит эти строчки?)


    today *= 1.1;
    total += today;

Comment: Для наглядности, чтобы запустить и увидеть как оно изменяется внутри. А дальше сам разберется куда `printf` пихать, чай переместить строчку — не ракетная наука.

Comment: а хотя! все отлично! спасибо  всем :) все понял!)
да и принт вынес за цикл... все окей :) всем спс))

Comment: отметьте данный ответ как "Правильный"

Comment: Добавил комментарии, на здоровье. Главное — разберитесь как оно работает.

Comment: спасибо drdaeman :)
я правда только познаю С, но эта задача особо не сложная :) просто немного запутался ... все сложное еще впереди)